# how to embed YouTube channel URL in php?

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-channels

I am trying to embed YouTube channel URL in my php page. But it gives following error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/fakecode' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

```
<div id="bgvideo" >
                <div class="container" >
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <div class="responsive-video">
                                <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/channel/fakecode" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');  try setting this header to your php file or blade file

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Why are you trying to embed a channel in your web page? Are you trying to embed a video or playlist instead?

Comment: @MartinBean Yes,I am trying to embed a video or playlist

Comment: Check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```